# VMware Workstation guest OS (Windows) resets date/time to host on restart

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, time, vmware-workstation

Everytime I restart my windows guest machine, it resets the date/time to the host date/time.

How can I change it permanently?

UPDATE: **Time sync is already disabled in VMware tools**

Comment: http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmware_timekeeping.pdf

Comment: Can't you just change the timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

No matter what I tried in the .VMX file or options to set, it always seems to sync the time.

To solve it, I booted in to safe mode and actually disabled the VMware tools service. I cannot remember now if it was the whole tools or if there was just one that was for time sync.

Then edited the time.

This worked and survived a reboot.

Answer (score 3):

Base on your VMware Workstation version you have to use "0" or "false".
For Vmware Workstation 10 its working with these settings:

```
tools.syncTime = "FALSE"
time.synchronize.continue = "FALSE"
time.synchronize.restore = "FALSE"
time.synchronize.resume.disk = "FALSE"
time.synchronize.shrink = "FALSE"
time.synchronize.tools.startup = "FALSE"
time.synchronize.tools.enable = "FALSE"
time.synchronize.resume.host = "FALSE"
```

You can use also `rtc.startTime = "1416441600"` to let the machine start with specific date and time - in this example its 20.11.2014. That number are seconds starting from 1.1.1970

Info from: http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1189

Comment: Could you explain how this is different and better from the two similar answers from '10 and '09?

Comment: These other answers do not work for Vmware Workstation 10. When its set as "0" , its ignored. You have to use "false" instead.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was the windows synchronization service. I disabled automatic time update with the time servers and now it stays changed.

UPDATE: **Turns out I was wrong, it DID change back after a while. Disabling VMware service does work!**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the VMware tools installed in the guest, you might try

```
tools.syncTime = "FALSE"
```

in your .vmx file.

[A related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276965/how-to-keep-a-vmware-vms-clock-in-sync)

Comment: It's already in the file (by default)

Comment: Ah, I see.  You may be out of luck.  I suspect VMware is setting the emulated hardware clock based on your host clock when it starts the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you guest windows virtual machine is joined to the same domain as your host machine and syncing to the server who has the  PDC emulator role.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to disable the VMWare service, it is useful for other reasons. Try setting **all** the time sync related settings:

```
tools.syncTime = 0
time.synchronize.continue = 0
time.synchronize.restore = 0
time.synchronize.resume.disk = 0
time.synchronize.shrink = 0
time.synchronize.tools.startup = 0
```

I was experiencing the same problem you are seeing, and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the .VMX didn't contain any of these parameters except tool.syncTime = "False".
Just try to edit/add these parameters to the .VMX file
tools.syncTime = 0
time.synchronize.continue = 0
time.synchronize.restore = 0
time.synchronize.resume.disk = 0
time.synchronize.shrink = 0
time.synchronize.tools.startup = 0

After setting up a desired time in guest OS and after reboot, it came up properly with the desired time.

Thanks guys.